# How to ignore NaN in column length check

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the maximum and minimum length of each column in a dataframe which has some missing values. Pandas treat those missing values as "NaN" and counts the length as 3. How do I completely ignore missing values while calculating maximum and minimum length?
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    columnname=[]
    maxColumnLenghts = []
    minColumnLenghts=[]

    for colname in df.columns: 
        columnname.append(colname)
        
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        
            minColumnLenghts.append(min(df.iloc[:,col].astype(str).apply(len)))
            maxColumnLenghts.append(max(df.iloc[:,col].astype(str).apply(len)))
```

Here is my dataframe: You would notice that column c has missing values(pandas converts it into NaN) and hence minimum length of column c is coming as 3 which is incorrect.
[image]

Comment: Can you please give a sample input `DataFrame` and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking method from previous answer, but you may want to use [pandas.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to get rid of NaN's and convert each value into string before counting min and max lengths.
My suggestions is:

```
col_stats = {}

for col in df:
    min_length = df[col].fillna(method='ffill').astype(str).str.len().min()
    max_length = df[col].fillna(method='ffill').astype(str).str.len().max()
    col_stats[col] = [min_length, max_length]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
col_stats = {}

for col in df:
    min_length = df[df[col].notna()][col].str.len().min()
    max_length = df[df[col].notna()][col].str.len().max()
    col_stats[col] = [min_length, max_length]
```

`col_stats` would then be a dict of colnames each including min,max pairs like,

```
{
  "col_1": [
    1,
    6
  ],
  "col_2": [
    10,
    32
  ],
  ...,
  "col_n": [
    5,
    52
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.How do I get the minimum length?

Comment: How do you mean by "length", don't you need to get count of not missing values of a column?

Comment: No I am not interested in count of missing values. I am interested in knowing the maximum and minimum length of the values in the column..By length I mean if the column value is 12349 then the length is 5.

Comment: Oh, OK. Your approach is correct as far as I can see, no better way to improve that approach. However, I would suggest slight changes, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve my original problem that its considering the length of NaN(missing vales) as 3. Is there a way I can way I can ignore missing values while calculating length.

Comment: Sorry forgot about Na's I fixed it